# Highmaps Select Multiple Points With Clustering Enabled Loses What Is Selected Already

Tags: highcharts

I need to allow users to select multiple lat/long points (cities) on a map that would add them to a list of already selected areas. If they click on an already selected area it will be removed from the selected list. This works great. I now need to implement point clustering as some areas have a lot of points to show and it gets messy. I have added this. However, now if you click on a set of points not in a cluster and then click on a cluster to zoom to that point and select one or more or none and then click Reset Zoom to get back to initial load all the points selected are now un-selected.

Reproducible example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ytpm9hjo/1/).
Steps to reproduce:

- Click on "Santiago de Compostela" and "Malaga" (note that they now
  turn red) and then click on "Get Points" button. This should write
  those two names to the console.
- Now click on the "6" cluster between those two points. Click on
  "Reset Zoom" and note that the 2 initial    points are no longer red.
  Click on "Get Points" - nothing is written to console.
- Click on those two cities again such that they are red. Now click on
  the "6" cluster between those two points again and click on "Faro"
  (note it turns red). Now click on "Get Points" - note that only
  "Faro" is written to console. Now click on "Reset Zoom" and click on
  "Get Points" again - nothing is written to console.

I would expect any existing points to still be selected regardless of cluster point or "Reset Zoom" button being clicked.

My code to select the points looks like:

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      if (typeof this.name !== 'undefined') {
        var clickedPoint = this,
          chart = this.series.chart;

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.points.forEach(function(p) {
            if (p.x === clickedPoint.x) {
              p.select(null, true);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

I then use this list of selected points in a different function:

```
$('#GetPoints').click(function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  var selects = chart.getSelectedPoints();
  $(selects).each(function(y, point) {
    if (point.selected) {
      console.log(point.name);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which you are struggling to is related to chart rendering after the zoom exit or the issue is also visible while resizing.

What you need to do is to keep somewhere information which points have been selected and set it to select again after the chart redraw.

My idea of how to achieve it by keeping the selected point in the global array `storedPoints`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/duzypvbj/

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      if (typeof this.name !== 'undefined') {
        var clickedPoint = this,
          chart = this.series.chart;

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.points.forEach(function(p) {
            if (p.x === clickedPoint.x) {
              p.select(null, true);

              // add the first point to array
              if (!storedPoints.length) {
                storedPoints.push(p.x)
              }
              // if point doesn't exist in array - add it
              if (!storedPoints.filter(point => point.x === p.x).length) {
                storedPoints.push(p.x)
              }

              // clean array if point is unselected
              if (!p.state) {
                console.log('test')
                console.log(storedPoints)
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know what do you think about this kind of solution.

Comment: That is the fix! I was going down that road but tied myself in knots. I had to make one fix in my code on the `chart.events.render` to see if the point is in the `storedPoints` and is already selected to not then run `p.select(null, true);` as that then unselects that point. If i could upvote more i would.

Comment: I am glad I could help! :)